# Pycaret, predict soil moisture to minimize water consumption

Tags: python, time-series, regression, forecasting, pycaret

I want to predict soil moisture for a field to minimize water consumption. For that I recorded only soil moisture and soil temperture over the course of two months. There are four devices that give me the values in 10min interval for one field. So I did combine those four soil moisture values in a moving average.
Here is an illustration of the training data:
[image: The diagram shows soil tension over time. Low values mean the soil is moistured, high means it is dry. Deep negative slopes or gradients means it is being watered atm.]
The diagram shows soil tension over time. Low values mean the soil is moistured, high means it is dry. Deep negative slopes or gradients means it is being watered atm.
Due to the fact that I want to predict how the soil is drying over time, I have to get rid of the watering periods. For every specific plant and soil type there is another threshold. Later I want to show the farmer when this threshold is expected to be met. Visualized below:
[image: this is how it should look like, created in paint ;)]
This is how it should look like, created in paint ;)
I identified them with the slope or gradient between the soil moisture values.
[image: Irrigation times highlighted]
Irrigation times highlighted
I seperated those into different training examples:
[image: separated training examples]

Separated training examples
Due to the fact that I want prototype this first, I used pycaret to benefit from high level functions that can compare models on the fly.
So I got 4 dataframes now, with the following head:

```
index = new index 0-end
orig_index = original index in df (before split)
Time = datetime64
hour = feature created from Time, hour of the day
minute = feature created from Time, minute of hour
date = feature created from Time, day of month
month = feature created from Time, month of year
grouped_soil = grouped soil humidity from B2, B3, B4
grouped_resistance = grouped soil resistancefrom B2, B3, B4
grouped_soil_temp = grouped soil tempfrom B2, B3, B4
rolling_mean_grouped_soil = rolling mean of frouped soil humidity
rolling_mean_grouped_soil_temp = rolling mean of frouped soil temp
B2_solar_x2_03, Soil_tension = raw soild tension value from sensor
B2_solar_x2_03, Resistance  = raw soil resistance value from sensor, will be calculated with temp to soil tension
B2_solar_x2_03, Soil_temperature  = raw soil temp value from sensor
B3_solar_x1_02, Resistance  = raw soil resistance value from sensor, will be calculated with temp to soil tension
B4_solar_x1_03, Soil_tension = raw soil tension value from sensor
B4_solar_x1_03, Resistance  = raw soil resistance value from sensor, will be calculated with temp to soil tension
B4_solar_x1_03, Soil_temperature  = raw soil temp value from sensor
gradient = slope, to indicate rapid changes (watering periods)
```

Now let's get to my question:

1. Do I train now four independent models? How can I combine those models afterwards? I tried it with blend_models() function in pycaret, but since I got different training data, it was not possible to combine them.
2. I cannot combine them to one model, because the irrigation times were different, so the time would be wrong(hour, day, month), right?
   For reference, this is my setup function:

   from pycaret.time_series import *
   exp=[]
   for i in range(len(cut_sub_dfs)):
   exp.append(TSForecastingExperiment())

   ```
    # check the type of exp
    type(exp[i])

    # init setup on exp
    exp[i].setup(
        cut_sub_dfs[i], 
        target = 'rolling_mean_grouped_soil', 
        enforce_exogenous = False, 
        fh = 50, 
        session_id = 123, 
        fold = 3,
        ignore_features = ['Time', 'orig_index', 'gradient']    
    )
   ```

Here is the returned:

```
Description Value
session_id1231
Targetrolling_mean_grouped_soil
ApproachUnivariate
Exogenous VariablesPresent
Original data shape(1911, 16)
Transformed data shape(1911, 16)
Transformed train set shape(1861, 16)
Transformed test set shape(50, 16)
Rows with missing values0.0%
Fold GeneratorExpandingWindowSplitter
Fold Number3
Enforce Prediction IntervalFalse
Splits used for hyperparametersall
User Defined Seasonal Period(s)None
Ignore Seasonality TestFalse
Seasonality Detection Algoauto
Max Period to Consider60
Seasonal Period(s) Tested[2, 3, 4, 25, 5, 26, 27, 6, 13, 7, 14, 18, 19, 22, 20, 21]
Significant Seasonal Period(s)[2, 3, 4, 25, 5, 26, 27, 6, 13, 7, 14, 18, 19, 22, 20, 21]
Significant Seasonal Period(s) without Harmonics[26, 27, 20, 25, 18, 21, 14, 19, 22]
Remove HarmonicsFalse
Harmonics Order Methodharmonic_max
Num Seasonalities to Use1
All Seasonalities to Use[2]
Primary Seasonality2
Seasonality PresentTrue
Target Strictly PositiveTrue
Target White NoiseNo
Recommended d1
Recommended Seasonal D0
PreprocessFalse
CPU Jobs-1
Use GPUFalse
Log ExperimentFalse
Experiment Namets-default-name35USIcbbb
```

These are the results:
[image: Many models perform bad, the best ones seem to be overfitted.]
Many models perform bad, the best ones seem to be overfitted.
3) Why are some models perform good, others bad on this data?
And finally, I used plot_model function to forecast:
[image: This is the forecast within the forecast horizon fh=50]
This is the forecast within the forecast horizon fh=50
[image: This is the forecast after the forecast horizon fh=500, 450 values after data ends.]
This is the forecast after the forecast horizon fh=500, 450 values after data ends.

I did not used predict_model function with new data, because this will only contain the times, because I do not know any other values in advance.

4. Why is my prediction that bad after the forecast horizon?

Further information:
I did not split a testset on my own in this example and evaluated. I just saw from the beginning that it is not worth it with those curves.
If you want me to upload a notebook with the code, I can do this, no problem.

Greetings and thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide the complete code with the dataset, I can try to look into it. It might also be better to open this as an issue on the GitHub repo itself as it may come to the developer's attention faster:

https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/issues